# How to dynamically create an object based on a readonly tuple in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I can define the properties of a type based on a readonly tuple with the following construct:

```
const keys = ['A', 'B', 'C'] as const;

type T = { [key in typeof keys[number]]: boolean; };
```

This behaves as expected:

```
const t1: T = {A: true, B: true, C: true}; // OK
const t2: T = {A: true, B: true}; // Type error
```

Now, let's say that I want to dynamically create an object of type `T` based on the `keys` array, e.g. using `reduce()` or ES2019's `Object.fromEntries()`:

```
const t1: T = keys.reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: true }), {}); // Type error
const t2: T = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(s => [s, true])); // Type error
```

In both cases, I need an explicit type assertion to stop the compiler from complaining:

```
const t1: T = keys.reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: true }), {}) as T; // OK
const t2: T = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(s => [s, true])) as T; // OK
```

Can anyone suggest a way to declare and initialize an object of type `T` based on the `keys` array, without having to resort to an object literal or explicit type assertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `Object.create(null)` instead of `{}` to initialise the object. This is cheating a bit, because `Object.create` has return type `any` which means you don't get a type error simply because the type isn't checked.

```
function makeObject<K extends PropertyKey, V>(keys: K[], value: V): Record<K, V> {
  const obj: Record<K, V> = Object.create(null);
  for(const k of keys) {
    obj[k] = value;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

The upside is that because the object has `null` as its prototype, it doesn't inherit properties like `'toString'` which might mess up code which expects dynamically-accessed properties to definitely have type `V` if they exist. If you explicitly do want to inherit those properties, you can use `Object.create({})` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can consider augmenting type definition of `ObjectConstructor`

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
  fromEntries<T = any, K=string|number>(entries: Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, T]>): { [k in keyof K]: T };
}
const keys = ['A', 'B', 'C'] as const;
type T = { [key in typeof keys[number]]: boolean; };
const t2: T = Object.fromEntries<boolean, T>(keys.map(s => [s, true])); // no Type error
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @ABOS, that in your case it can be useful to consider augmenting of global types, however, I understand, that some times it is not an option - strict eslint rules, team code guides etc ...

I know only one solution to type correctly Array.prototype.reduce in your particular case:

```js
const keys = ['A', 'B', 'C'] as const;

type T = { [key in typeof keys[number]]: boolean; };

const t1: T = { A: true, B: true, C: true }; // OK
const t2: T = { A: true, B: true }; // Type error

const result = keys.reduce<T>((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: true }), {} as T) // T
```

You just need to explicitly cast initial value of reduce. This problem is also related to typing of `setState` method in react. See open issue [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635).

**Regarding to `Array.prototype.map`.**

In your case you can type your mapping function in next way:

```js
type Mapped<Arr extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>, Result extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> = []> =
    Arr extends []
    ? [] : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? readonly [...Result, readonly [H, true]] : Arr extends readonly [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Mapped<readonly [...Tail], readonly [...Result, readonly [Head, true]]> : Readonly<Result>

type Result = Mapped<MyArray>; //  readonly [readonly ["A", true], readonly ["B", true], readonly ["C", true], readonly ["D", true]]

/**
 * Because arrays are mutable in JS,
 * you are unable to type result variable as Result directly
 * 
 * One thing you can do is to use cast operator - as
 * I hope you don't mutate your arrays inside [map] callback
 */
const result = keys.map<Result[number]>((s) => ([s, true] as const)) as unknown as Result
```

**Regarding `fromEntries`.**

Same as `Object.keys`, `fromEntries` will not return correctly typed keys of source objects, it made purposely by TS team, because, like I already said, JS mutable nature.

You have two ways here, the way which was introduced by @ABOS, or type casting - through `as` operator.

For example, there is a common pattern of using `Object.keys`:

```js
const obj = { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
const keys = Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj> // ("foo" | "bar")[]
```

Please keep in mind, it is still workaround, it is not 100% type safe, because of mutable nature of JS.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string) you can find more about Object.keys

I know, you did not ask about, Object.keys, but it is still same problem as `fromEntries`

**Summary:**
There are two ways: augmenting global type definition or using type casting. Each way is not completely safe, but if you are not mutating your arrays/objects it is ok to use it.

P.S. I believe there are more ways to achieve it, just because I prefer functional programming, I did not provide any example with mutable data structures, but if you are ok with mutating, @kaya3 solution is good

Comment: To be clear, you can use `Object.create` in the `reduce` solution to avoid a type assertion, too - I just write it using a loop because the `reduce` solution creates unnecessary temporary objects and takes O(n^2) time.

Comment: @kaya3 very clever solution with Object.create(null). Did you use it in PROD? I'm just worry what if smbd wants to call some native method on object?

Comment: If you want those native methods then `Object.create({})` works instead. However, when I have an object with dynamic properties, I make sure to use e.g. `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, ...)` instead of `obj.hasOwnProperty(...)` so that just in case one of the dynamic properties happens to be named `'hasOwnProperty'` then the code will still work.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks for clarification. Good to know!